# Choose a folder dialog for nsis

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have a problem with the skin that I am using for my nsis installer. 
Is there a way to control to not apply skin to choose a folder dialog. 
I am using Skincrafter plugin to apply this skin. 
Generally if I load it after initializaiton, it applies to all pages/inner dialogs and child dialogs. I do not want Browse for a folder dialog to have a skin. 
Can someone please provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to fix this from NSIS.

Asks the authors to add this feature for you or (if the sources are available) modify the it by yourself to fit your needs.

There are also some other skinning systems for NSIS - e.g. mine [Graphical Installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com) (sorry for this little promo :) so you can try to use them.